# MySQL python: Cursor returns the variable name

Tags: python, mysql, string, cursor

I saw before if someone ask the same but i didn't see a similar question.

```
def get_session(Var = '', Key=''):
    conn = connection()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    print "Var: "+Var
    cursor.execute("Select %(var)s FROM users WHERE sessions = %(key)s",{'var':Var,'key':Key})
    if(cursor.rowcount == 1):
        name = cursor.fetchone()
        print name
        return name
```

The output is like:

```
get_session(Var = 'NAME', Key='asdf123')
```

> Var:NAME
>
> ('NAME',)

```
+----+----------+----------+---------------------------+
| ID | NAME     | PASS     |  sessions                 |
+----+----------+----------+---------------------------+
|  1 | Potato   | test     |  asdf123                  |
|  2 | asdf123  | test2    |  asdasd                   |
+----+----------+----------+---------------------------+
```

The correct output must be:

```
get_session(Var = 'NAME', Key='asdf123')
```

> Var:NAME
>
> ('Potato',)

or

```
get_session(Var = 'PASS', Key='asdf123')
```

> Var:PASS
>
> ('test',)

I supposed that the main problem is that mysql detects the name with quotes but i don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the quotes that sql put in automatically

```
def get_session(Var = '', Key=''):
    conn = connection()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql = "Select "+ Var+" FROM users WHERE sessions = %(key)s"
    print "Var: "+Var
    cursor.execute(sql,{'key':Key})
    print str(cursor.rowcount)
    if(cursor.rowcount == 1):
        name = cursor.fetchone()
        print name
        return name
    else:
        return None
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

Thanks to all for responding.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
cursor.execute("Select %s FROM users WHERE sessions = '%s'" %("Name","asdf123"))
```

So query becomes :

```
Select Name FROM users WHERE sessions = 'asdf123'
```

You can use variables as well
Eg:

```
name_of_col = "Name"
session_name = "asdf123"

cursor.execute("Select %s FROM users WHERE sessions = '%s'" %(name_of_col,session_name  ))
```